# how do i fix(udpate) this code of my event handler in react Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i use to have the following handler for updating my local state and for multiples inputs in my react component

```
const [input, setInput] = useState({
  name: "",
  minW: "",
})
const handlerInput = (e) => {
  setInputs({
    ...inputs,
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
  });
}
```

but i update my code so my state is now this

```
const [input, setInput] = useState({
  name: { info: "", error: "" },
  minW: { info: "", error: "" },
});
```

how do i update my event handler to work correctly ?

i do not know how to fix my function can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried replacing `e.target.value` with your new object structure?  (And using `e.target.value` to set either `info` or `error` on that object, presumably?)

Comment: What would "working correctly" mean? We don't know what it's supposed to do.

Comment: I have multiple text inputs rendering in my component with the same handler in an onchange event. I need that when writing to my input, the info property of my state dynamically corresponding to each input is filled

Comment: Can you show the jsx code?
Also I can see that you have declared the state as input and setInput but in the handler you are calling setInputs and spreading inputs. Your state names are singular and the handler uses pluralized names

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the value of the `input` to change the `info` field, this might work for you:

```
// State declaration
const [input, setInput] = useState({
  name: { info: "", error: "" },
  minW: { info: "", error: "" },
});

// Handler
const handlerInput = (e) => {
  setInputs({
    ...inputs,
    [e.target.name]: {
      ...inputs[e.target.name],
      info: e.target.value,
  });
}
```

However, react hooks were designed to separate concerns like these. I see 4 unique components of your updated states, so I think you should separate them with 4 separate `useState`s:

```
// State declaration
const [name, setName] = useState("");
const [error, setError] = useState("");
const [minW, setMinW] = useState("");
const [minWError, setMinWError] = useState("");

// Handlers
const handleNameInput = (e) => {
  setName(e.target.value);
}
const handleMinWInput = (e) => {
  setMinW(e.target.value);
}

// I'm not sure how you use the "error" states, 
// but you could make more handlers for them
```

Comment: It **may** make sense to separate the state, but if they all follow the same pattern (or it's a "collective" state needed elsewhere) it may not. That aside, if they all have info/error it might make more sense to create a wee custom hook and abstract away that detail.

Comment: I completely agree Dave. It's tough to tell because there's a lot of contest missing in the question.

Comment: Once we know too much we're just targets. Best to not know too much, I say! :rofl: